# Univocity - parse each TSV file row to different Type of class object

Tags: univocity

I have a `tsv` file which has fixed rows but each row is mapped to different Java Class.

For example.

```
recordType  recordValue1
recordType  recordValue1 recordValue2
```

for First row I have follofing class:

```
public class FirstRow implements ItsvRecord {

    @Parsed(index = 0)
    private String recordType;

    @Parsed(index = 1)
    private String recordValue1;

    public FirstRow() {
    }
}
```

and for second row I have:

```
public class SecondRow implements ItsvRecord {

    @Parsed(index = 0)
    private String recordType;

    @Parsed(index = 1)
    private String recordValue1;

    public SecondRow() {
    }
}
```

I want to parse the TSV file directly to the respective objects but I am falling short of ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an `InputValueSwitch`. This will match a value in a particular column of each row to determine what `RowProcessor` to use. Example:

#### Create two (or more) processors for each type of record you need to process:

```
final BeanListProcessor<FirstRow> firstProcessor = new BeanListProcessor<FirstRow>(FirstRow.class);
final BeanListProcessor<SecondRow> secondProcessor = new BeanListProcessor<SecondRow>(SecondRow.class);
```

#### Create an `InputValueSwitch`:

```
//0 means that the first column of each row has a value that 
//identifies what is the type of record you are dealing with
InputValueSwitch valueSwitch = new InputValueSwitch(0);

//assigns the first processor to rows whose first column contain the 'firstRowType' value
valueSwitch.addSwitchForValue("firstRowType", firstProcessor);

//assigns the second processor to rows whose first column contain the 'secondRowType' value
valueSwitch.addSwitchForValue("secondRowType", secondProcessor);
```

#### Parse as usual:

```
TsvParserSettings settings = new TsvParserSettings(); //configure...
// your row processor is the switch
settings.setProcessor(valueSwitch);

TsvParser parser = new TsvParser(settings);

Reader input = new StringReader(""+
        "firstRowType\trecordValue1\n" +
        "secondRowType\trecordValue1\trecordValue2");

parser.parse(input);
```

#### Get the parsed objects from your processors:

```
List<FirstRow> firstTypeObjects = firstProcessor.getBeans();
List<SecondRow> secondTypeObjects = secondProcessor.getBeans();
```

#### The output will be*:

```
[FirstRow{recordType='firstRowType', recordValue1='recordValue1'}]

[SecondRow{recordType='secondRowType', recordValue1='recordValue1', recordValue2='recordValue2'}]
```

- Assuming you have a sane toString() implemented in your classes

#### If you want to manage associations among the objects that are parsed:

If your `FirstRow` should contain the elements parsed for records of type `SecondRow`, simply override the `rowProcessorSwitched` method:

```
    InputValueSwitch valueSwitch = new InputValueSwitch(0) {
    @Override
    public void rowProcessorSwitched(RowProcessor from, RowProcessor to) {
        if (from == secondProcessor) {
            List<FirstRow> firstRows = firstProcessor.getBeans();
            FirstRow mostRecentRow = firstRows.get(firstRows.size() - 1);

            mostRecentRow.addRowsOfOtherType(secondProcessor.getBeans());
            secondProcessor.getBeans().clear();
        }
    }
};
```

- The above assumes your `FirstRow` class has a `addRowsOfOtherType` method that takes a list of `SecondRow` as parameter.

#### And that's it!

You can even mix and match other types of `RowProcessor`. There's another example [here](https://github.com/uniVocity/univocity-parsers/blob/master/src/test/java/com/univocity/parsers/examples/CsvParserExamples.java#L568) that demonstrates this.

Hope this helps.