# Break CSV into multiple parts with Univocity

Tags: csv, parsing, text, univocity

I have a CSV with multiple datasets in it. For ex,

```
FIELD1, 10, FIELD2, 20, FIELD3, 30 // dataset1 begins here
FIELD4, 40, FIELD5, 50 // line 2 of dataset1
SUBFIELD1_ROW1, 100, SUBFIELD2_ROW1, 200 // subsection of dataset1: line1
SUBFIELD1_ROW2, 300, SUBFIELD2_ROW2, 400 // subsection of dataset1: line2
SUBFIELD1_ROW3, 500, SUBFIELD2_ROW3, 600 // subsection of dataset1: line3
FIELD1, 10, FIELD2, 20, FIELD3, 30 // dataset2 begins here
FIELD4, 40, FIELD5, 50 // line 2 of dataset2
SUBFIELD1_ROW1, 100, SUBFIELD2_ROW1, 200 // subsection of dataset2: line1
SUBFIELD1_ROW2, 300, SUBFIELD2_ROW2, 400 // subsection of dataset2: line2
SUBFIELD1_ROW3, 500, SUBFIELD2_ROW3, 600 // subsection of dataset2: line3
// dataset 3
// dataset 4 and so on
```

Is it possible to break this CSV into 4 parts (one for each dataset)? I looked through the test classes on Univocity GitHub page but couldn't find a similar example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [example](https://github.com/uniVocity/univocity-parsers/blob/f616d151b48150bc9cb98943f9b6f8353b704359/src/test/java/com/univocity/parsers/examples/CsvParserExamples.java#L664). Basically you need to use an `InputValueSwitch` that targets the first column. Add a switch for "FIELD1", another for "Field4" and another one for "SUBFIELD". You need to associate a different processor to each possible row type using:

```
inputSwitch.addSwitchForValue(<your column matcher>, processorForRowWhereMatcherReturnsTrue);
```

What happens when the format of the row changes is for you to decide. You can override

```
public void rowProcessorSwitched(RowProcessor from, RowProcessor to)
```

Of the `InputValueSwitch` to do whatever you need.

Check these other related questions:

[Univocity - parse each TSV file row to different Type of class object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38388588/univocity-parse-each-tsv-file-row-to-different-type-of-class-object/38392613#38392613)

[Univocity CSV parser multiple beans with multiple rows in single CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51882254/univocity-csv-parser-multiple-beans-with-multiple-rows-in-single-csv/51960652#51960652)

[Modifying complex csv files in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36143952/modifying-complex-csv-files-in-java/36164474#36164474)